# Ajax function in javascript can not check whether the XML is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, error-handling

```
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t === "timeout") {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        else if(t === "parsererror") {
            alert("Error in reading the XML file.");
        }
        else if(t === "abort") {
            alert("The XML request is aborted.");
        }
        else{
            alert("Encounter error in reading XML.");
        }
    }
```

These are the default error-checking method provided by ajax function, however, it does not check whether the file is empty or not. Is there any way to fix this problem? Also , are there other typical error cases I should handle? Thanks

Comment: If the response is empty it doesn't mean that this is an error case. Check for empty string in `success`.

Comment: Yea, just check if the data's `""`, yourself.
A "Empty response" isn't a error, though. It can be a perfectly valid response.

Comment: thanks I got it. However, I just think of another possible error case , which is a duplicate node , Is it possible to let ajax function check it for me? thanks

Comment: @user782104 Again it goes to another request handler.

Comment: sorry would you mind telling more specific? Do i have to do progamming  like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613629/removing-duplicate-xml-node-by-keeping-the-first-occurence-using-xslt

Comment: `x.responseText` will give you the return value as a string

Answer (score 0):

> Yea, just check if the data's "", yourself. A "Empty response" isn't a error, though. It can be a perfectly valid response.